# AWS IOS SDK + Facebook Login Issue

Tags: ios, aws-sdk, xcode9

I am trying to log-in on Facebook with AWS IOS SDK, my code as below:

```
[[AWSFacebookSignInProvider sharedInstance] setPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"]];
[[AWSFacebookSignInProvider sharedInstance] setViewControllerForFacebookSignIn:self];
[[AWSIdentityManager defaultIdentityManager]
 loginWithSignInProvider:[AWSFacebookSignInProvider sharedInstance]
 completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"^Login in with SignIn Provider has failed: %@", error);
         completion(NO);
         return;
     }
     completion(YES);
 }];
```

In response of loginWithSignInProvider, I am getting an error as below:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=306 "Access has not been granted to the Facebook account. Verify device settings." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Access has not been granted to the Facebook account. Verify device settings., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorLocalizedDescriptionKey=Access has not been granted to the Facebook account. Verify device settings.}

Here I am using Xcode 9.2 and IOS 11.0, Can please help me to solve that issue.

Comment: Do you have FB permission for `user_friends` ?

Comment: Yes, it is default permission and it is working fine now. 
It may be issue from AWS or FB, after a day, it was resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [AWSFacebookSignInProviderCustom new];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (void)login
{

    if (!self.facebookLogin)
        self.facebookLogin = [FBSDKLoginManager new];

    [self.facebookLogin logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]
                                         handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                             if (error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Error!");
                                             } else if (result.isCancelled)
                                             {
                                                 // Login canceled, do nothing
                                                 NSLog(@"Cancelled!");
                                             } else {
                                                 NSLog(@"FSBKDAccess Token: %@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);
                                                 [[AWSFacebookSignInProvider sharedInstance] login];

                                             }
                                         }];
}
```